# ASP.NET Core - Property VALUE to camelCase in JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json, camelcasing

I have a SQL Tables containing definition of dynamic grids (I'm using AGGrid library for Angular).
Example:

**TB_AGGrid_Definitions**

| ID | GridKey |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TestGrid |

**TB_AGGrid_Columns**

| ID | GridId | Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FirstColumn |
| 2 | 1 | SecondColumn |

I'm using ASP.NET Core with EF Core for creating backend webapi service for my Angular Web application.
I have a controller which can retrieve grid information.

Example JSON

```json
{
   "grid":{
      "id":1,
      "gridKey":"TestGrid",
      "columns":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "gridId":1,
            "field":"FirstColumn"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "gridId":1,
            "field":"SecondColumn"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I just would like to transform the value of `Field` property in `camelCase` using the same alghoritm of JsonSerializer.
I need to do this for binding properly the objects and the grid column definition which is case-sensitive.
If I send to AGGrid `FirstColumn` as a field, it won't work with an object that has property named `firstColumn` (which will be default behavior after default serialization).

I have fields like:

`"IDTabella" --\> "idTabella"`

`"IDDTUltimoCommission" --\> "idDtUltimoCommission"`

`"NDGCliente" --\> "ndgCliente"`

Automatic serialization works perfectly, but I can't replicate the same result with my own function.

Expected JSON

```json
{
   "grid":{
      "id":1,
      "gridKey":"TestGrid",
      "columns":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "gridId":1,
            "field":"firstColumn"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "gridId":1,
            "field":"secondColumn"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: "replicate the same result with my own function" - what code/function?  Perhaps post actual code we can help you fix here.

Comment: .NET is open-source so why not just look at the implementation hosted on Github if you want to *"use the same algorithm as `JsonSerializer`"*.

Comment: Hi @MarkSchultheiss, it was generale sentence for saying "I could implement my own function that converts string in camelCase, but I won't have the same result because I didn't know the algorithm of JsonSerializer". Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specifically asked for the `camelCasing`-algorithm that the `JsonSerializer` uses in .NET. Here is the implementation of that taken from the official open source repository for the .NET runtime on Github (See [Github - dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5568ac9e1a7215e9ac1c84f0c79c7da8b16d1e50/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/Common/JsonCamelCaseNamingPolicy.cs#L8)).

> Implementation on current `main` branch with the last commit having the hash `3138a80` which is already after .NET 8 was released.
>
> [Go to Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/Common/JsonCamelCaseNamingPolicy.cs)

```cs
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

namespace System.Text.Json
{
    internal sealed class JsonCamelCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
    {
        public override string ConvertName(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || !char.IsUpper(name[0]))
            {
                return name;
            }

#if NETCOREAPP
            return string.Create(name.Length, name, (chars, name) =>
            {
                name.CopyTo(chars);
                FixCasing(chars);
            });
#else
            char[] chars = name.ToCharArray();
            FixCasing(chars);
            return new string(chars);
#endif
        }

        private static void FixCasing(Span<char> chars)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1 && !char.IsUpper(chars[i]))
                {
                    break;
                }

                bool hasNext = (i + 1 < chars.Length);

                // Stop when next char is already lowercase.
                if (i > 0 && hasNext && !char.IsUpper(chars[i + 1]))
                {
                    // If the next char is a space, lowercase current char before exiting.
                    if (chars[i + 1] == ' ')
                    {
                        chars[i] = char.ToLowerInvariant(chars[i]);
                    }

                    break;
                }

                chars[i] = char.ToLowerInvariant(chars[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As one would imagine it's quite well implemented with performance in mind i. e. avoiding heap allocations mainly by using [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-8.0) where necessary and usage of some methods you would typically only use when you really care about performance (like [`string.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=net-8.0) here).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to know if there is some class or utils method that I can use just to convert a string. If not, I will implement a string extension method with this implementation

Comment: This class is internal so you can't create an instance of it, so you can't use that directly. I am not aware of any built-in methods to do this in .NET. And I'd be very surprised if there was. If there was a general API to convert `PascalCase` to `camelCase` (which this does) I'd assume they would have used it. I guess there'll be libraries for this but don't think it's worth introducing a library over this (I'd assume you'd agree with that from what I understand from your comment).